# increase background size while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, background-size

i have a problem. i'm building a parallax website and one eyecandy is while you scrolling, the background size are increasing. at first i think that wont be a problem, because i use the background-position snippets solution which is:

```
var x = $window.scrollTop();
$('.stage.intro').css('background-size', '10' + parseInt(x / 10, 0) + '% ');
```

this is works fine for a while, but when the scroll reached the 109th percent, the background looks terrible. a question. how can i handle this? [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6jr3mcee/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `'10' + 10` is equal to `'1010'`, *not* `110`. You're instantly jumping from 109% to 1010% - a much larger value. All you need to do is change that `'10'` to be a numerical `100`:

```
$('div').css('background-size', 100 + parseInt(x / 10, 0) + '% ');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6jr3mcee/1/).

Comment: Thank's James! I'm always flaming people, who don't able to remember the number string relations in javascript. And i'm now the people... :)